# Php multidimensional array output

Tags: php

I have an example:

```
$foo = array(1 => array(1=> 'lol',2=>'lolol'),2=>array(1 => 'sda', 2 => 'dss'));
```

How can I output this...what need to be passed to the loop, give me an example please.Thank you

Comment: please clarify what you're looking for because it's not very intelligible ...

Comment: I need an array that I can execute like this `$fg[1][2]`and it needs to return a specified thing for that ID(1) and option(2)

Comment: it appears you already have the array. are you looking for how you might loop over it to get specific values?

Comment: "*and it needs to return a specified thing for that ID(1) and option(2)*" ...wut? Sorry.. I don't exactly understand what you want to achieve here.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some ways. You didn't say how you needed the output.

```
print_r($foo);

var_dump($foo);

foreach($foo AS $key => $value)
{

    print_r($value);

}
```

Comment: Arraystring(5) "Array" 
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in

Comment: It need to return the option, for example for 1 it need to return lol

Comment: if you want it to return option one for each you could do:

   foreach($foo AS $key => $value)
 {
 
 echo $value[1];
 
 }

otherwise you can just access it vie: echo $foo[1][1];